# MDT: Imaging different hardware types?

Tags: windows-xp, mdt-2010

We use numerous make and model of laptops in our research. To this point we've always used "ghost" to image them (w/ XP). Im wondering about the feasibility of using MDT instead.

Would I need a separate image for each make / model or is there some way to generalize an installation so it will work on different types of hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, where you are is exactly where we were about two years ago. Jump head first into MDT and luxuriate in the freedom of the single image :-)

You will need three tasks ideally (IMO - many people combine tasks 1 & 2)

1 build vanilla XP SP3

(then install all the software you want on this machine)

2 capture the 'reference' machine.

3 deploy the captured image to all other devices.

Comment: So I need an image with drivers specific to that model?

Comment: No, you gather all the drivers in your domain and add them to the "out-of-box drivers" section. Then as MDT deploys the image it'll grab whatever drivers it needs from that list (in theory :-) )

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the current thinking when using MDT is not to image them but to "deploy" them.  A "deployment" consists of the base OS (thick or thin) + model specific drivers, plus any apps for the particular role you are deploying.  Driver management can be as specific as you want.  See [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2008/03/13/microsoft-deployment-toolkit-lite-touch-video-walk-through.aspx) for a video walkthru of how to deploy a system with MDT

Answer (score 2):

To expand a little on [Kieran's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/370558/111860) you can get driver packs that will help you out too.

Dell put out drive packs on their [community wiki.](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/enterprise-client/w/wiki/2065.dell-driver-cab-files-for-enterprise-client-os-deployment.aspx)

Also you can user [Driverpacks.net](http://driverpacks.net/) too.